# how to change the target of ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Given:

```
<input ng-model="prop1">
```

How can I change the target of ng-model from 'prop1' to 'prop2'? The following changes the attribute value in the DOM but the directive does not react to that.

```
angular.element('input').attr('ng-model', 'prop2');
```

I can recompile the element and then it works:

```
angular.element('input').attr('ng-model', 'prop2');
$compile(angular.element('input'))($scope);
```

But that leaks watches, I can tell using Batarang's Performance tab.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of changing the model in the DOM, why not simply reference a different object on the $scope variable that is the model? `$scope.prop1 = myothermodelobject`

Comment: I can't do that. Instead of `prop1` and `prop2`, think of `employee.firstName` and `employee.lastName`: `<input ng-model="employee.firstName">` and I need to change what `ng-model` binds to.

Comment: Instead of binding to `employee.firstName` bind to a different object such as `employee.activeEditField` and then you can can swap the value of said field in the scope to contain firstName or lastName as needed. Why are you trying to avoid doing it this way?

Comment: If I do that, I'll have to `$watch` the `activeEditField` and the currently bound attribute (`firstName`) to synchronize their values as they change. I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

use an intermediary value to store both

```
<input ng-model="prop">

$scope.prop = prop1
```

then later

```
$scope.prop = prop2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.